# Pyrocms Getting Values at front end

Tags: database, pyrocms

I am new to pyrocms.
How can I get database values on pages of pyrocms. In website of pyrocms I had created a listing page now I want to display database values from pyro database table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got your question, you want to create a listing on your front-end page for some database table values which you want to access through your custom module controller. there are many ways to get these values but the simplest way is to use ajax. you already have Jquery added in pyrocms so you can simply make a call to your controller method in ajax and get your required output as HTML and display it in the div element on your page.

```
 $.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:"admin/your-controller-name/your-method-name",
  success:function(html){
    $('yourdiv').html(html); 
  }
})
```

In your controller create a method which get data from database and print it using echo create some listing table etc what you want.

i think you will get my point. if confuse then get back to me

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more specific as PyroCMS has lots of components and each module (blogs, variables, widgets, file uploads etc.) uses specific tags you insert into the page. You may come across references to 'Lex' - that's the name of the parser used to display them.

[Tags documentation](http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.1/manual/concepts/pyrocms-tags)

PyroCMS (the Professional edition) also has a feature called "[Streams](http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.1/manual/pro/pyrostreams)" which allows you to build custom databases and this in turn has it's own series of tags.